# Bash script appending existing array element to array in loop splitting on space (whitespace?)

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

Can someone please tell me why it is splitting my value into two array elements upon appending to a new array?

Here is my code, with output below...

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'toexec=($(cat /root/devops/commands.txt))'
#printf '%s\n' "${toexec[@]}"
dirlist=(`ls /root/devops/files/*`)
toCompress=()
toOutput=()
for fileList in ${dirlist[*]}
do
  toOutput+=($(basename ${fileList}));
  toCompress+=("${fileList}"$'\n');
done
newOut=()
printf '%s\n' "${toexec[@]}"
for (( i=0; i<${#toexec[@]}; i++ ));
do
    newval="${toexec[$i]},${toOutput[$i]}"$'\n';
    newOut+=($newval);
done
echo "======"
printf '%s\n' "${newOut[@]}"
```

Here is the output, separated by =====, existing array on top, new array on bottom.
As you can see, it is putting each element into two elements, splitting on the single space between `gzip` and its `option,filename`, for example `gzip` and `-1,a.txt`.

**OUTPUT**

```
gzip -1
gzip -9
======
gzip
-1,a.txt
gzip
-9,b.txt
...
==debug additional info==
--toexec < commands.txt--
gzip -1
gzip -9
=========================
--toCompress < ls--------
=========================
/root/devops/files/a.txt

/root/devops/files/b.txt

----toOutput-------------
a.txt
b.txt
=========================
----newOut---------------
gzip
-1,a.txt
gzip
-9,b.txt
=========================
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @Cyrus, seriously, that spellcheck thing is awful.   You should stop telling people to use it, I almost had my script working, now I have to start over, losing many hours.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the value is not double quoted, as in

```
newOut+=("$newval")
```

That would add a single element to the array.